# get text from the textbox of one form to another in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I had entered some data in the TextBox and selected item in a combobox in form2 and want to use same data in form1  how can I do so....
I tried this code
`frmConfig` is form2 and `txtSrcIP` is the TextBox

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
    frmConfig f2 = new frmConfig();

    public Form1(frmConfig Cont)
    {
            f2 = Cont;
    }

    String SIp = f2.txtSrcIP.text;
}
```

The error is showing in this line `String SIp = f2.txtSrcIP.text;` 
as A field initializer cannot reference the non static field method or property

frmConfig body
public partial class frmConfig : Form
    {
        private Form1 f1;

```
    public frmConfig()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



            // Open connection to the database
            string conString = "server="+txtSrcIP.Text+";uid="+txtSrcUserId.Text+";pwd="+txtSrcPwd.Text; 

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();

                // Set up a command with the given query and associate
                // this with the current connection.
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from sys.databases", con))
                {
                    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            cbSrc.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbSrc.SelectedItem != null && cbSrc.SelectedItem != "" && cbDest.SelectedItem != null && cbDest.SelectedItem != "")
        {

            this.Hide();
            //Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Show();

            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter all the details");
        }
    }

    }
```

this is what i am doing so i want all the textbox and combox value in form1

Comment: You need to raise an event when some state changes. Checkout observer pattern : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: String SDb = f2.cbSrc.SelectedItem.ToString();
error = object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static frmConfig f2 = new frmConfig();
```

So, how about these changes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
    static frmConfig f2 = new frmConfig();

    public Form1(frmConfig Cont)
    {
        f2 = Cont;
    }

    public String SIp;
}

...

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbSrc.SelectedItem != null && cbSrc.SelectedItem != "" && cbDest.SelectedItem != null && cbDest.SelectedItem != "")
    {

        this.Hide();
        //Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.SIp = f2.txtSrcIP.text;
        f1.Show();

        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter all the details");
    }
}
```

Comment: It helped with textbox but value of combobox is not retriving

Comment: Could you include the `frmConfig` class definition? Or at least, the `ComboBox` definition?

Comment: that's probably because your form controls are still not initialized

Comment: if (f2.cbSrc.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                 SDb = f2.cbSrc.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }

Answer (score 2):

Create a public property on `f2` that exposes the `Text` property of the control you require.

```
public string TxtSrcIPValue
{
    get
    {
        return this.txtSrcIP.text
    }
}
```

Then use this property to access the value.

```
Private string SIp;
public Form1(frmConfig Cont)
{
        f2 = Cont;
        SIp = f2.TxtSrcIPValue;   // Set the value once the form has been loaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The control you want to use, change 'modifier' property so you can acces it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759.aspx), A variable initialiser for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created, so you need to initialise the fields in the constructor instead.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
    frmConfig f2;
    String SIp;

    public Form1(frmConfig Cont)
    {
        f2 = Cont;
        String SIp = f2.txtSrcIP.text;
    }
}
```